The order of center of any non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$
Let $G$ be a non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$ with $n>3$.
In
this  paper
there is (just after Lemma 2.10) a statement which says $p^2 \leq |Z(G)|\leq p^{n-2}$.
I know that the center of a $p$-group is non-trivial. I also know that $|Z(G)|$ can not be $p^{n-1}$ or $p^n$. But my question is that why $|Z(G)|$ can not be $p$. I would be grateful if someone could help me about it. Thanks in advance.

This isn't true, try with the smallest nonabelian $p$-group you know.

For $n\leqslant 3$ your statement is inconsistent.

@SteveD I said this statement from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333554357_Some_properties_on_mathrmIA_Z_IA_Z_-automorphisms_of_groups/fulltext/5cf3ab0a92851c4dd0212bba/Some-properties-on-mathrmIA-Z-IA-Z-automorphisms-of-groups.pdf between Lemma 2.10 and Theorem 2.11.

@ancientmathematician I meant $n>3$ here.

Sorry, but it just isn't true. If it were, by applying it repeatedly (even for $n>3$) would say every group of order $p^n$ had nilpotency class at most $(n+1)/2$, which is absurd.

@Mahtab If you meant it you should have said it: otherwise communication is impossible.

@ancientmathematician You are right. I'll edit my question.

I think the close votes are too harsh here. If this were a "Prove or disprove..." exercise, I understand closing, because there are plenty of small counterexamples. But since this was in a paper, I understand the inclination to believe it's true, and try to prove it. So I'm not convinced this should be closed. @Mahtab, now that you know it's false, you should answer your own question with a counterexample.

@SteveD If the question were edited to cite the given paper and not just mention it in a remark then I'd agree: that would be the "details" that are missing.

Let's give people the time to realize what's going on before starting closing (after all, they promised "...to edit [their] question...")

@Kan't That was a different issue, that edit did take place.

Again, let's give them a while to realize also that the source has to be cited in the question. I'd lend by default an exemption time to question/answer before being scored anyhow.

@SteveD When I was reading the paper, I guess that this is false but I said to ask the experts about that. You are right. I will try to give a counterexample and answer my question. Thank you very much for your help.

@Mahtab In fact I don't think that the statement really helps the proof of their Thm 2.11, if $Z(G)$ is order $p$ there's nothing else to prove anyway. So I don't know why it's in the paper. BTW if it  helps I think a nice counterexample is the group of upper unipotent matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

@ancientmathematician That's right because by the hypothesis of the theorem, $Z(G)=G'$ and if $|Z(G)|=p$, then $G'$ is cyclic. I think your idea.  I really appreciate your help.

Refer to this paper link, you can check group $F_9$ of order $p^4$ which has center of order $p$.

Authors of the paper write en passant

We recall that the centre of any non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$ lies between $p^2$ and $p^{n-2}$.

Setting aside the grammar error (it's the order of the center that would lie there, not the center itself), the assertion is false.
An easy counterexample is the dihedral group of order $8$ and the quaternion group of order $8$. Another are the nonabelian groups of order $p^3$.
Even requiring $n\gt 3$ does not solve the problem. Another infinite family of examples of arbitrarily large order is furnished by the extra-special $p$-groups. These are $p$-groups of order $p^{2n+1}$ in which $Z(G)=G'=\Phi(G)$ is cyclic of order $p$.
Although all the examples above are of class $2$, there are examples of arbitrarily large class as well. A $p$-group of maximal class is a finite group $G$ of order $p^n$ and nilpotency class $n-1$; they exist for every prime $p$ and every $n\geq 3$. See here for references and an explicit construction for odd $p$ here. For $p=2$, the dihedral group, quaternion group, and semidihedral group of order $2^n$ are all of maximal class and hence have cyclic center of order $2$.
